# Flutter: vscode can luanch ios simulator but can't connect it

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

I tried to select command line tools in Xcode. it's still notworking.
but Xcode can run on ios simulator

I want to run flutter app on ios simulator in vscode

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written a launch configuration in vscode?

Comment: I don't write launch configuration because I don't know how. please advice me.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/vs-code#run-app-in-debug-profile-or-release-mode

Answer (score 1):

To run a Flutter app on an iOS simulator in VS Code, you can follow these steps:

Install Flutter and the Flutter extension in VS Code if you haven't already done so.

Open the project folder in VS Code.

In the terminal, navigate to the project folder by using the `cd` command.

Use the command `flutter devices` to check if any iOS simulators are available.

If an iOS simulator is not listed, open Xcode and create a new simulator by going to `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator.`

Once a simulator is available, use the command `flutter run -d <device id>` to run the app on the simulator. Replace  with the ID of the simulator you want to use. You can find the ID by running the flutter devices command.

Wait for the app to build and launch on the simulator.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is running from vscode, this is running from terminal. And the answer is suspiciously close to a GPT answer...

Comment: These are the common steps followed to resolve these type of issue.
If you can provide more context related to the issue you are facing then I probably give you a more accurate solution.

Comment: I can build and launch app via xcode but vscode still can't connect  ios simulator. that shown in below photo

Comment: In the bottom bar of VS Code, there is a section that displays devices. By clicking on it, you can see a list of all available devices. From there, you can start the iOS simulator, and once it is open, you can run your app on it using `flutter run command` 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm in the same situation than you. How could you resolve that impediment?

Answer (score 0):

I use macbook pro 2012.
macOS: catalina 10.15.7
xcode: 12.4
flutter: 3.11
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).